# How do I Express this PHP in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need a neat and tidy and elegant way to do this in Ruby. It is a simple get what is on the page and out put it to the screen.

```
<!--?php 
echo file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
?-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`net/http`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) like this:

```
require 'net/http'
puts Net::HTTP.get('google.com', '/')
```

You can also use `get_print`, like this:

```
Net::HTTP.get_print('google.com', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://google.com')
p Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

You can read more on this topis in documentation [here](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html).